# Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID - class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I need to work with `Ivi.Visa.Interop` assembly version 5.0.0.0 for a C# based .NET Framework 4.0 windows desktop application. I'm using `Visual Studio 2015`.

This assembly has a class `FormattedIO488`. When I try to instantiate this class:

```
FormattedIO488 f = new FormattedIO488();
```

I get the following error at runtime:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {DB8CBF1D-D6D3-11D4-AA51-00A024EE30BD} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

A quick Googling revealed that the target platform for my project has to be x86. It is x86 but I'm getting this error. The OS on which I'm developing is `Windows 10 x64`.

What does "class not registered" mean? How can I register a class?

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you registered the DLL? From memory, at the command line, something like `regsvr32 my_library.dll` (brings back some awful memories!)

Comment: @DavidG: Why do I need to register a DLL?

Comment: When trying to register, I got this error: `The module "Ivi.Visa.Interop.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.`

Comment: Because COM was a terrible way to do things in the past. Each type in a COM library has a GUID that needs to exist in the registry. And you can imagine the pain if you ever needed to run two different version of the same library in different projects (TL;DR don't!)

Comment: @DavidG: Any idea what I should do now?

Comment: Not really I'm afraid, you may need to talk to the supplier of that DLL. Does it have any companion DLLs that need registering perhaps?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149367/discussion-between-donotalo-and-davidg).

Comment: @Donotalo did you resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem using an interop DLL in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10 x64.

Comment: @markp3rry: I've forgotten! Poor me!! What the last thing I remember is that probably I needed to instantiate a derived class of `FormattedIO488`, but I'm not sure. May be you can find a solution and post an answer here. I no longer work on that project.

Comment: Not sure if this is still an issue- but we found that setting the application pool to enable 32-bit applications was a fix for seeing this exact error. Good times! hope this helps.

Comment: Anything new regarding this issue? Im also have the exact same problem? I get the error: 80040154 and "The module "Ivi.Visa.Interop.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found" when I try register the dll

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same issue and in my case the library i was trying to use specifically required .Net 3.4 to run. Long story short you need to install .net or just download the software suite the the manufacturer released with the library. in my case you will need to download this suite:
https://www.keysight.com/us/en/lib/software-detail/computer-software/io-libraries-suite-downloads-2175637.html

Here is a note that came with it, essentially its a known issue:
Notes on .NET Framework 3.5/2.0 and Known Issues:
Just as Keysight IO Libraries Suite 2021, users are no longer forced to install .NET Framework 3.5/2.0 during installation.
Users can choose to install .NET Framework 3.5/2.0 when they run the installer silently and with an additional command line switch. For example: IOLibSuiteInstaller_version.exe /s /z"typical;net35"
If users want to use VISA.NET drivers which are provided by the IVI Organization rather than Keysight Technologies, Inc., then they must install .NET Framework 3.5/2.0.
You may need to install .NET Framework 3.5 for 32-bit VISA applications to work.